# Bookshelf circular dependency with ES5

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have the following code:

```
const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf');
const BaseModel = require('bookshelf-modelbase')(bookshelf);
const moment = require("moment");

const User = require("./User");
const Meta = require("./Meta");
const Log = require("./Log");

class Session extends BaseModel {
    get tableName() {
        return "sessions";
    }

    get hasTimestamps() {
        return false;
    }

    user() {
        return this.belongsTo(User);
    }

    meta() {
        return this.belongsTo(Meta);
    }

    logs() {
        return this.hasMany(Log);
    }
};

module.exports = Session;
```

and

```
const bookshelf = require('../config/bookshelf');
const BaseModel = require('bookshelf-modelbase')(bookshelf);
const Session = require("./Session");
const moment = require("moment");

class Log extends BaseModel {
    get tableName() {
        return "logs";
    }

    get hasTimestamps() {
        return false;
    }

    session() {
        return this.belongsTo(Session);
    }

    getDate() {
        return moment(this.get("date")).format("MMM DD, YYYY - HH:mm:ss")
    }
};

module.exports = Log;
```

`belongsTo` relation works properly, but when I try `hasMany`, I get: "Unhandled rejection Error: A valid target model must be defined for the sessions hasMany relation" error.

I had a look at https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry but it is being done using pre-ES5 syntax.

I guess I need to make sure "Log" class is available before I appoint into a hasMany relationship but stuck here.

Any ideas?

Edit: Doing

```
logs() {
    var log = require("./Log");
    return this.hasMany(log);
}
```

works but it looks bad.

Comment: The Bookshelf registry is exactly what you need. Why Pre-ES5 syntax is a problem ? Can't you adapt it ?

Comment: There is no example about how to do it with class syntax. Plus, words like "Load the plugin on your Bookshelf instance using Bookshelf.plugin('registry')." makes no sense. I'm not sure where I should add that code into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Bookshelf registry. It exactly fits your needs.

You can load Bookshelf registry plugin like this :

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: config.db_host,
        user: config.db_user, // user name for your database
        password: config.db_password, // user password
        database: config.db_database, // database name
        charset: 'utf8',
    },
});

const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
bookshelf.plugin('registry');

module.exports = {
    knex,
    bookshelf,
};
```

Then, register your models in module.exports like this :

```
module.exports = {
    session: db.bookshelf.model('Session', Session),
    log: db.bookshelf.model('Log', Log),
    db,
};
```